# how to persist the pointer increment

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have the following code

```
   void fun(int * d)
   {
    d+=1;
   }

   int main()
   {
      int * f=malloc(5);
      f[0]=0;f[1]=1;f[2]=2;f[3]=3;f[4]=4;
      fun(f);
      printf("value : %d\n",*f);
      return 0;
   }
```

So, i pass an integer pointer to function and increment it there. I want that increment to persist when it returns to main. 
When I print the value, The output is '0'. But I want the output to be '1' as I have incremented the value in function.

So, briefly, my question is, how to persist the changes made to a pointer?

Comment: Also, `malloc(5)` will allocate 5 bytes, which is most often not the same as 5 ints.

Comment: As @BoPersson said, you should do `malloc(5*sizeof(int))` to get the correct amount of memory, or `malloc(5 * sizeof *f)` in case you ever change your mind about `*f` type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to increment the *pointer*, **not** the value, you have two options:

1. recast the function to `void fun(int ** d)`,  use `(*d)+=1;` in the function body, and call using `fun(&f);`
2. recast the function to `int* fun(int* d)`, and *return* the new value.

If you want to increase the *value*, then use `(*d)+=1;` in the function body.

You don't need the parentheses around `*d`: I've put them in for clarity.

Comment: Now, I want to persist the changes made to pointer when nested function calls are involved.
main() calls fun1() and fun1() calls fun2(). changes are made to pointer in fun2(). How to persist them in main function? Use a tripple pointer??

Comment: No, you can maintain two levels of indirection. Probably best if you ask a new question with a good quality supporting code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot * in d+=1;

When you pass that pointer you have access to f[0] with that approach:
Take a look here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void fun(int *d){
    *d+=1;
}

int main(void){
    int i;
    int *f=malloc(5 * sizeof int);

    f[0]=0;f[1]=1;f[2]=2;f[3]=3;f[4]=4;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%d ",f[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    fun(f);

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%d ",f[i]);
    }
    free(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> 0 1 2 3 4 
> 1 1 2 3 4
> ```

Or if you try to add +1 to all elements you can do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int *fun(int *d, int len){
    int i;
    int *newArray = d;
    int newValue = 1;

    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        newArray[i] += newValue;
    }

    return newArray;
}

int main(void){
    int i;
    int f[] = {0,1,2,3,4};
    int *newArray;

    f[0]=0;f[1]=1;f[2]=2;f[3]=3;f[4]=4;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%d ",f[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");



    newArray = fun(f,5);

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%d ",newArray[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> 0 1 2 3 4 
> 1 2 3 4 5
> ```

And by the way you forgot to free **f**.

Comment: Plus one for spotting the leak.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the *address* of the pointer, so:

```
void fun(int **val) {
    *val++;
    ....
}
int main() {
    ...
    fun(&f);
    ...
}
```